# Simple DataFrame question from a beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning dataframe now. I've been stuck in how to get a subset of a dataframe or table with its label index. I know it's a very simple question but I couldn't find the solution in pandas documentation. Hope someone could help me. Appreciate your help.

So, I have a dataframe named `df_teams` like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUkJm.png)

If I want to get a subtable of a specific team *'Warriors'*, I can use `df_teams[df_teams['nickname']=='Warriors']`, resulting a row in the form of dataframe. My question is, what if I want to get a subtable of more teams, say I want information of both 'Warriors' and 'Hawks' to form a new table? Can I do something similar by using logical index and finishing in one line of code?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example instead of posting a screenshot? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a bitwise or on the two conditions using the '|' character.

```
df_teams[(df_teams['nickname']=='Warriors')|(df_teams['nickname']=='Hawks')]
```

Alternatively if you have a list of values you want to check against you could instead use the isin method to return rows that have one of the values present in the list.

E.g

```
df_teams[df_teams['nickname'].isin(['Warriors','Hawks'])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The latter solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, happy to help